# Update: Swiftui function is called before other one is completed

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, async-await

So I'm building an app with `Swift` and Firebase. I have a problem when trying to save a user's profile information.

When I press the save button it calls a function that begins by uploading the 4 pictures to imgur and then a url is returned:

```
 let urlFoto1 = await uploadImageToImgur(image: foto1)
 let urlFoto2 = await uploadImageToImgur(image: foto2)
 let urlFoto3 = await uploadImageToImgur(image: foto3)
 let urlVerificar = await  uploadImageToImgur(image: fotoVerficar)
```

After this an array with all the info is created and is uploaded to Firebase:

```
var userData: [String : Any]       

userData = ["uid": uid,"nombre": nombre, "sobreMi": sobreMi, "genero": genero, "busco": generosSeleccionados, "foto1": urlFoto1, "foto2": urlFoto2, "foto3": urlFoto3, "fotoVerificar": urlVerificar]
        
Firestore.firestore().collection("usuarios")
    .document(uid).setData(userData) { err in
     ...
}
```

My issue is that the userData is always uploaded to Firebase before the pictures urls were returned (resulting in urlFoto1 = ""... in my database). I've tried different await/async/task combinations but I just don't get it. I'm very new to swift.

Here's the code for the imgur upload function (I found it online):

```
func uploadImageToImgur(image: UIImage) async -> String {
    var imgurUrl = ""
    await getBase64Image(image: image) { base64Image in
        let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.imgur.com/3/image")!)
        request.addValue("Client-ID 7fa33a0074850d7", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        var body = ""
        body += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
        body += "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"image\""
        body += "\r\n\r\n\(base64Image ?? "")\r\n"
        body += "--\(boundary)--\r\n"
        let postData = body.data(using: .utf8)

        request.httpBody = postData

        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("failed with error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                print("server error")
                return
            }
            if let mimeType = response.mimeType, mimeType == "application/json", let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {

                print("imgur upload results: \(dataString)")

                let parsedResult: [String: AnyObject]
                do {
                    parsedResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]
                    if let dataJson = parsedResult["data"] as? [String: Any] {
                        print("Link is : \(dataJson["link"] as? String ?? "Link not found")")
                        imgurUrl = dataJson["link"] as? String ?? ""
                       
                    }
                } catch {
                    // Display an error
                }
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
    return imgurUrl
}
```

Pls help :(

**UPDATE**:
So I've made some changes and at least it does work now. However I don't know if it's the best approach... I switched to Firebase storage for the images but since there are 4 images I had to put every upload inside the other and at the end the function that saves all the info to Firestore is called. Here's the code:

```
private func guardarFotos() {
        
        //Sacar el id del usuario
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{return}
        
        //Path de las fotos
        let refFoto1 = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "fotos/\(uid)/foto1")
        guard let foto1Data = foto1.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) else {return}
        let refFoto2 = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "fotos/\(uid)/foto2")
        guard let foto2Data = foto2.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) else {return}
        let refFoto3 = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "fotos/\(uid)/foto3")
        guard let foto3Data = foto3.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) else {return}
        let refFotoV = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "fotos/\(uid)/fotoV")
        guard let fotoVData = fotoV.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) else {return}
        
        
        refFoto1.putData(foto1Data, metadata: nil) {metadata, err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error subiendo foto1: \(err)")
                return
            }
            
            refFoto1.downloadURL { url1, err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error descargando url foto1: \(err)")
                    return
                }
                
                print("Correcto url foto1: \(url1?.absoluteString ?? "")")
                
                refFoto2.putData(foto2Data, metadata: nil) {metadata, err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error subiendo foto2: \(err)")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    refFoto2.downloadURL { url2, err in
                        if let err = err {
                            print("Error descargando url foto1: \(err)")
                            return
                        }
                        
                        print("Correcto url foto1: \(url2?.absoluteString ?? "")")
                        
                        refFoto3.putData(foto3Data, metadata: nil) {metadata, err in
                            if let err = err {
                                print("Error subiendo foto3: \(err)")
                                return
                            }
                            
                            refFoto3.downloadURL { url3, err in
                                if let err = err {
                                    print("Error descargando url foto3: \(err)")
                                    return
                                }
                                
                                print("Correcto url foto3: \(url3?.absoluteString ?? "")")
                                
                                refFotoV.putData(fotoVData, metadata: nil) {metadata, err in
                                    if let err = err {
                                        print("Error subiendo fotoV: \(err)")
                                        return
                                    }
                                    
                                    refFoto3.downloadURL { urlV, err in
                                        if let err = err {
                                            print("Error descargando url fotoV: \(err)")
                                            return
                                        }
                                        
                                        print("Correcto url fotoV: \(urlV?.absoluteString ?? "")")
                                        
                                        subirDatos(url1: url1!.absoluteString, url2: url2!.absoluteString, url3: url3!.absoluteString, urlV: urlV!.absoluteString)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

The function that uploads to Firestore:

```
private func subirDatos(url1: String, url2: String, url3: String, urlV: String){
            //Sacar el id del usuario
            guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{return}
            
            var userData: [String : Any]
            
            userData = ["uid": uid,"nombre": nombre, "sobreMi": sobreMi, "genero": genero, "busco": generosSeleccionados, "foto1": url1, "foto2": url2, "foto3": url3, "fotoVerificar": urlV]
            
            Firestore.firestore().collection("usuarios")
                .document(uid).setData(userData) { err in
                    print("Error guardar: \(err)")
                    problemaGuardar = true
                    return
                }
        }
```

Any suggestions on how to make this better? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want `uploadImageToImgur` should return the uploaded image path?

Comment: You need to use an async/await function instead of URLSession.shared.dataTask and await its completion.

Comment: Suggestion; use Firebase Storage for your images. All of that code could be replaced with about 8 lines. Observation: The calls you're using, including firebase, are asynchronous so you have to allow for that. Lastly, finding code online is fine but if you don't understand it, don't use it. Write your own or take the time to follow the flow so you know what/how it does what it does. We don't want too troubleshoot someone else's code.

Comment: Your updated code is fine, but a bit repetitive. You could leverage an escaping closure and put the writes in a loop OR you could use DispatchGroups so the calls will flow one after the other - either of those methods would reduce the code by about 75% since you're essentially doing the same thing 4 times. Also, if the order of writing doesn't matter, everything in Firebase is asynchronous so there are other options as well.